# How to return a url from a server side method in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, server-side, html-encode

Simple question that we've spent to much time on. We have a server side function that creates a URL for an image (similar to a gravatar identicon), but it's output is being html endcoded, which is probably causing a few issues.

```
...
<asp:image ID="Image1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' ImageUrl= '<%= GetURL(Eval("UserID").ToString()) %>'></asp:image>
...
```

We end up with:

```
 <img id="Image1" title="123456789" src=""http://www.ourwebsite.com/image/123456789&amp;s=128&amp;s=identity&amp;p=userid"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can avoid encoding by assigning image url in the code behind like this:

Image1.ImageUrl = GetURL(userId);

Comment: Got this to work. Turned out to be easiest for me since I was already performing this function. Possibly the other solution worked but not for me...

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a call to [HttpServerUtility.Decode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) either on the page directly or in the `GetURL` method.

```
ImageUrl= '<%= HttpServerUtility.Decode(GetURL(Eval("UserID").ToString())) %>'
```

Comment: I believe the function name is htmlDecode, and now I'm getting even stranger output: src="Modules/Upload/3C%25=%20HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode(GetURL(Eval(%22UserID%22).ToString()))%20%25%3E"